# Styling an Image within a Text Component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to style an  which is in a Text component. As far as I read in much forums, it is not possible to give it a margin, width, height. What I am basically trying to do is to get a result like this:

[Result wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IVcW.png)

The thing is, if I wrap everything within a View component as the parent, the image will also get a little above the text and I won't be able to style it.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can style Image inside Text Component as below and get as in the pic provided by you

```
 <Text> Hello I am  
  <Image
      style={{   width: 30, 
        height: 30,}}
      source={require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png')}
    />
  {"Text after image" }

 </Text>
```

Comment: That's the problem that I am facing. Using the code that you have provided, I cannot style the Image so it will be inlined with the text correctly. I cannot give margin for example. Instead, I get a result like this [link](https://imgur.com/gMWd28y) @RuchiTiwari

Answer (score 0):

For the alignment you can also go this way

```
    <View
      style={{flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center', justifyContent:"center"
      }}>
   <Text> {"Text before image"}</Text>
   <Image
      style={{   width: 30, alignSelf:"center",
        height: 30,}}
      source={require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png')}
    />
   <Text> {"Text after image" }</Text>
   </View>
```

The result as in this [link](https://snack.expo.dev/XLl26LSwp)

Comment: If you want to go with the Image within Text component itself then you can try styling image with  position:"absolute"     Hope this helps   <Image
      style={{   width: 30,  position:"absolute",
        height: 30,}}
      source={require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png')}
    />

Comment: This solution works. But there is a problem. Since every text is a component by itself, they are treated line by line. I want to make it look as everything is like one text.

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageBackground.

```
 <Text> Hello I am  
  <ImageBackground>
      style={{   width: 30, 
        height: 30,}}
      source={require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png')}
     resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image}>

     <Text style={styles.text}>Inside</Text>

    </ImageBackground>
  {"Text after image" }

 </Text>
```

Read [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Text>Hello: I am{` `}
       <Image
         source={require('your image path')}
         style={{height: 20, width: 20}}
       />
       {` `}
       John Doe and I want to get a result like this with react-native
 </Text>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please?

Answer (score 0):

To make it look like one text, placed the result in this [link](https://snack.expo.dev/99w4HlfV4)  Let me know if this works. The margins and line spacing in the code can be adjusted through responsive screen size. This have placed for the reference

```
<Text style={{lineHeight: 25,}}>Hello I am 

 <Image
 style={{width: 30, height: 30, marginStart:15, marginEnd:15, 
 marginTop:15, marginBottom:-8}}
  source={require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png')}
 />
 
<Text style={{lineHeight: 25,}}> Comments like this are just amazing. 
</Text>

</Text>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the border radius isn't working on the image when it is a child of a text component. and I am facing an issue where the text is wrapping before finishing the line.